# Does an estimator need to be unbiased in order to be sufficient?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimators, unbiased-estimator, sufficient-statistics

I am reviewing some theoretical statistics content, and I was wondering if an estimator need to be unbiased in order to be sufficient? Is there any way to prove this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can multiply a sufficient estimator by anything (like, say, /(−1)) and it will stay sufficient but stop being unbiased